# SQL select instruction to create a new table from a existing table

Tags: sql, pivot

I'm looking for a sql instruction (Select) to create a table format from a existing table.

I have a table in this format.

```
Id|Record|Title  |Value|

 1. |1   |name   |John |
 2. |1   |ammount|200  |
 3. |2   |name   |Lisa |
 4. |2   |ammount|400  |
```

However I need to show information in this format

```
Record|Name|Ammount|

 1.   |John|    200|
 2.   |Lisa|    400|
```

I don't want to create a new table, I'm looking for a select or join operation.
Do you know any instruction to perform this operation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: `SELECT ... INTO` - Google is awesome

Comment: Please make up your mind. The title and first line say you want to create a new table. The last line says you don't want to create a new table.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT record, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN Title = 'name' THEN Value END) AS Name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Title = 'ammount' THEN Value END) AS Ammount
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY record
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a823/5)

Comment: 'create a new table' is part of the question.  Your query doesn't do that.

Comment: The question says _I don't want to create a new table, I'm looking for a select or join operation._

Comment: sorry, this question is junk, the title and first line do not agree with that.  Removing -1 as it's not your fault that the OP didn't ask a good question.

Comment: Does it really matter? Adding a `CREATE TABLE tablename AS` to the front of it is a trivial modification. The heart of the question is how to pivot the data.

Comment: I removed the -1 as stated, it's not your fault that the OP doesn't know how to ask a question.  I'm not sure if the OP wanted to see a select into or create table and insert / select OR neither.  Which is why I didn't answer.  Answering question which are so ambiguous is dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (assuming it's MySQL):

```
SELECT
    A.Record,
    A.Value AS Name,
    B.Value AS Ammount
FROM
    tbl A
JOIN
    tbl B
ON
    A.Record = B.Record
WHERE
    A.Title = 'name' AND
    B.Title = 'ammount'
```

Basically you join the same table twice through Record value, filter the results by Title column and select required columns.

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a823/3) example

Comment: Please use ANSI JOIN syntax, not old-fashioned cross-product.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT tt.record,
      (SELECT value FROM t WHERE tt.record = record AND title = 'name') AS name,
      (SELECT value FROM t WHERE tt.record = record AND title = 'ammount') AS ammount
  FROM t as tt
  GROUP BY tt.record
  ;
```

Comment: You should at least have `SELECT TOP 1` in case there are multiple - which would blow up your script.  Data problems are common ;)